# select query returns always -1 in edit

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, ado, c++builder

I have this code in C++Builder.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

AnsiString am="2323246";

   Form1->ADOQuery1->SQL->Text="SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.T_AM='"+am+"'";

   Form1->Edit1->Text=Form1->ADOQuery1->ExecSQL();

}
```

It always returns -1 as result in the editbox even if I tried other value for
am. The values exist in my database and if I try to execute query in my database it works
just fine and returns the correct ID.

Comment: T_ID is an integer and it is also the primary key for my table. T_AM is a varchar.

Answer (score 0):

What variable type is T_AM?  If it's an integer or float, lose the quotes.  Also, look at prepared queries or statements.  This type of query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Example:

```
PrepareSQL("SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE T_AM = %d", am);
ExecSQL();
```

You will need to check the API documentation for the exact semantics and syntax for doing this.

Looking at API, you need to do something like this:

```
VARIANT vName;
vName.vt = VT_BSTR; //Variant type for BSTR
vName.bstrVal = _bstr_t("2323246");

Form->ADOQuery1->Parameters->Append(
    Form->ADOQuery1->CreateParameter(_bstr_t("T_AM"),adChar,adParamInput,50,vName)
);
```

Comment: T_ID is an integer and it is also the primary key for my table. T_AM is a varchar.

Comment: It might be the database causing an issue if the row truly exists.  You could try using: "SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE T_AM IN ('%d')".  Or try using LIKE.

Comment: The sql query is fine because I have executed it in SQL Server 2005 and it worked perfectly. The problem may be in the format of the result. Because it is an integer. I suppose...

Comment: Is that single quote really needed when TABLE.T_AM is integer type.
Can you try as shown below?
"SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.T_AM="+am

Comment: I'd have thought you would get a type cast exception if that was the case.  I'm also not convinced ExecSQL will return the value.  I'd expect it to return the number of rows and store a pointer to the rowset, accessible through some iterator or method.

Comment: @graig T_AM is a varchar not an integer. T_ID is an integer. I tried to return the result in an integer like this                             but it again showed the same result...                     AnsiString am="2323246";

   Form1->ADOQuery1->SQL->Text="SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.T_AM LIKE '%"+am+"'";

   int res=Form1->ADOQuery1->ExecSQL();                  
   Form1->Edit1->Text=res;
}

Comment: It may be that the DB API is insisting on secure parameters.  Try using a prepared statement instead of trying to 'glue' the parameter to the statement.

Comment: @graig With IN() it returns 0 always... Here's the code...    AnsiString am="2323246"; Form1->ADOQuery1->SQL->Text="SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.T_AM IN ('%"+am+"')"; int res=Form1->ADOQuery1->ExecSQL(); Form1->Edit1->Text=res; }

Comment: How can I use the prepared statement? If I use it like this PrepareSQL("SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.T_AM IN ('%"+am+"')"); it shows an error...                               [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(695): E2268 Call to undefined function 'PrepareSQL'
  Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(683): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *)

Comment: You need to check the API documentation to find out how to created a prepared statement.  What API are you using?  Usually, they are called much like a printf statement.  Other variations use '?' as positional parameters.

Comment: Look at: http://www.codersource.net/C/CDatabase/CADOStoredProcedureUsingCommandObject.aspx

Comment: I have updated my original response with an example of what you may need to do to apply parameters to the SQL.  Most likely it uses the '?' variant of positional parameters: SELECT T_ID FROM TABLE WHERE T_ID = '?'

Comment: I will try that if it works and I will answer to you. Thank you very very much!!!